# copying the xml element data from one xml to another xml usin xslt

Tags: xslt

I am new to xslt. When i am using below piece of code for transformation from one form to another. is this below format correct?

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    xmlns:app="http://*/*/*/applicationRequest">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/app:ApplicationRequest/BusinessChannel">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$ApplicationBatchDocument/BusinessChannel"/>
   </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

> is this below format correct?

Short answer:
No. You are using an undefined variable `$ApplicationBatchDocument`.

Longer answer:
XSLT transforms an XML document from one schema for to another. If you don't show us what the input document looks like, and what do you want the output to look like, then no good answers are possible.